# How to upgrade Android 2 to 3 or 4 on GT-I9000?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, updates, rom-flashing, rom

All is in the title. I have got a GT-I9000 (samsung galaxy S) and I do not understand why I cannot upgrade the android version ?

Why an android version is linked to a specific phone ?

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/34075/5892) might have some helpful information for you.

Comment: Try to specify what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

First, you probably cannot update to Android 3.x as that version was only intended for tablets.

Second, no Android version is linked to a specific phone. But each phone needs specific adaptions due to different hardware elements used, so each Android version must be adapted to be usable on the device.

Third, for "How can I..." and "Where do I find..." and "When is it available...", please check the questions (and answers) already dealing with this:

- [How do I update the OS on my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/) (includes links to "When does my device get the Android x.y update" for most Android versions)
- [Can every Android device be updated to the most recent Android version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14267/)
- [What is involved in upgrading Android to a later version, if the manufacturer no longer supports the device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28784/)
- and others (check the "Related" and "Linked" sections of the questions)

Answer (score 2):

You can use not official builds (because no oficial updates), like [CyanogenMod](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?type=stable&device=galaxysmtd), but before flashing it, please, read [CyanogenMod forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/forum/83-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000/) and [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=656)!

Flashing new ROM will require to delete all your data from phone. And yes, by incorrect actions, you can easily break it.